# Getting junk data while getting items from document library using Rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx) link for reference to fetch data from document library using Rest api.

The issue I am facing is I am getting junk data in result. Below is my code sample:

```
<button type='button' onclick="retriveItems()">Copy document</button>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function retriveItems() {
    alert("Hello World");

    var requesturi= "";
    if((_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl) && (_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl.indexOf("sites")>0))
    {
        requesturi = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('"+_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/Shared%20Documents/teghjhs.docx')/$value";
    }
    else
    {
        requesturi = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/teghjhs.docx')/$value";
    }
    console.log(requesturi);
    $.ajax  
        ({  
            url: requesturi,
            type: "GET",   
            headers:  
            {  
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(data)   
            {  
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data.d.results[0].Title);                 
            },  
            error: function(data)  
            {  
                console.log('error occured');  
            }  
        });
}   
</script>
```

Below is output screenshot when I hover on data or add it in console:

[image]

[image]

Can someone suggest me how can I get data in correct json output?

Comment: Are you using this code in SP hosted app/ provided hosted app ?

Comment: Not currently. Just using content editor to get file.

Comment: Then use this url for request -- url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')

Reference Link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Comment: Do you want the document content or the associated columns data ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

It's the format of the document you are trying to read (i.e. docx).

SharePoint doesn't provide API to read the word file content. If you will try to read any other file with .txt format from your document library, it will read in proper format.

Refer this thread for more information :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f0274065-7d7b-4da6-87c5-cb3c50a38bfb/read-docx-file-with-rest-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: your provided link's accepted answer has two links. One redirect me to same stack overflow link I go through. The other uses word interop.  I can't use word interop with SharePoint Online.